# SchemaUpdate is not executed after running setup script

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, magento-2.1.7, upgradeschema

I am trying to run some `Setup\UpgradeSchema.php` lines. I run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And my module code is not executed. My `Setup\UpgradeSchema.php` looks more or less like this:

```
    if (version_compare($version, '100.0.24', '<')) {
        $this->makeLatLngFieldsDouble($setup);
    }
```

My `module.xml`looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="My_Module" setup_version="100.0.24">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales" />
            <module name="Magento_Quote" />
            <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
            <module name="Magento_Customer" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

My `setup_module` table looks like this:

```
Module      | schema_version | data_version
------      | ------         | -----
My_Module   | 100.0.23       | 100.0.23
```

When I run this on my local machine it works fine, however in my server it does not. The first time I executed it it gave me an error but now it is not, so I suspect of a caching problem. I have flushed the cache, and run:

```
rm -rf var/cache var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/di/ var/tmp/ var/view_preprocessed/;
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? I am using Magento 2.1.7 by the way

Comment: Just to confirm the setup_module table is taken from your local machine or the server?

Comment: From the server

Comment: Did you drop log on `Setup\UpgradeSchema.php`?

Comment: I do not find any log

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The problem was I was pointing another db Schema. So the `schema_version` and `data_version` were equal to my module's.